# Why put strings in curly braces in jsp

Tags: jsp

While editing existing JSP pages, I have found some code similar to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<mytaglib:url 
                 p1="blah" p2="${'/some/path/file.js'}" />">
</script>
```

`mytaglib:url` generates a URL which ends with p2.

Why is the path string put inside curly braces? I have also seen the same code where curly brackets are not used, and it seems to work fine. Is this is some habit that is not useful here? I am pretty sure I could remove the braces here, but can it happen in other situations that using expression language for a mere string is useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to ask some of the initial authors of the application I am modifying. None of them could tell me, it seems that this is actually useless (worse: it has a little performance overhead), was initially done by mistake and somehow replicated in many places in the codebase...

Answer (score 0):

`${}` is expression of JSP Expression Language. JSP Expression Language (EL) makes it possible to easily access application data stored in JavaBeans components.

Find out more about JSP Expression Language [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/unifiedel-139263.html#Expression_Language_Beginnings_)

Answer (score 0):

It is jsp expression language. When the JSP compiler sees the `${}` form in an attribute, it generates code to evaluate the expression and substitues the value of expression. It is similar to `<%=%>` in jsp.

You will get an idea from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm)

Here in this case, ${} accepts a string where it doesn't have to evaluate anything so returns the same string. Instead you can specify a variable name, in which case it evaluates value of the variable and returns the same

Comment: Thanks Sree. I know what expression language is, my question is why using it here? It decreases readibility but does not seem to have any use here.

Comment: Not sure about that. May be giving the path directly created some problems due to special characters.